# How to update a regex to not consider order in an or (  | ) statement or how to emulate:

Tags: php, regex

This regex

```
(<link\s+)((rel="[Ii]con"\s+)|(rel="[Ss]hortcut [Ii]con"\s+))(href="(.+)")(.+)/>
```

works for

```
<link rel="icon" href="http://passets-cdn.pinterest.com/images/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://css.nyt.com/images/icons/nyt.ico" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/careers/Img/favicon.ico?36da6b" />
<link rel="Shortcut Icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

but not for where the href and rel attributes are switched:

```
  <link href="/phoenix/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
```

How can I update it so the or statements are not ordered

so that

```
aa || bb
```

works just as well as

```
bb || aa
```

Test here:

http://regexpal.com/

I just want to pull the path from the favicon tag...I've chosen not to use a library.

**Stema's answer in different form:**

```
<link\s+
    (
        ?=[^>]*rel="
        (
            ?:[Ss]hortcut\s
        )
        ?[Ii]con"\s+
    )
    (
        ?:[^>]*href="
        (
            .+?
        )"
    ).*
/>
```

Comment: That is only for large html parsing not single tags.

Comment: I'm pretty sure scale is irrelevant.

Comment: it's based on chomsky grammars and complexity and is not relevant here:

Comment: regex is working well...just one line of code....just one tag grab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it with a positive lookahead

```
<link\s+(?=[^>]*rel="(?:[Ss]hortcut\s)?[Ii]con"\s+)(?:[^>]*href="(.+?)").*/>
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?31202)

You will find the path in the first capturing group.

The thing here is, that the lookahead is not matching anything. So you can check if somewhere within the tag there is `rel="(?:[Ss]hortcut\s)?[Ii]con"` and if this pattern is found it will match the `href` part and put the link into the capturing group 1.

`(?=[^>]*rel="(?:[Ss]hortcut\s)?[Ii]con"\s+)` this is the [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Thats indicated by the `?=` at the start of the group.

`[^>]` is a negated character class, that matches any character but the `>`. I use this to ensure that it does not pass the closing `>` of the tag.

Comment: @HiroProtagonist, I added more explanation.

Comment: I learned a **lot** here on SO and I like regex, maybe you are interested in my blog post [What absolutely every Programmer should know about regular expressions](http://wp.me/p2pTzU-4), but of course, lookahead assertions are advanced stuff and not covered by this basic article. Maybe I will write something about them in the future.

Comment: Thats the magic of assertions. They don't match anything, they just "look ahead" and assert that the stuff is following.

Comment: Yes, a group starting with `?:` is a non capturing group.

Comment: regex is working well...just one line of code....just one tag grab...awesome stuff.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot, not with a single regular expressions. Well, you actually can, but it is really not worth it, and you will end up with an unreadable mess of a regex.

Match against `/<link\s([^>]+rel="(shortcut\s+)?icon"[^>]*)>/i` and then match the captured part against `/\shref="([^"]+)"/i`.

Comment: regex is working well...just one line of code....just one tag grab...awesome stuff.

Answer (score 2):

You can use one regex to locate the icon tag and a second regex to pull the path.

If the only text that your second regex parses is a single tag it can be as simple as `/href="(.+)"/` and the order of attributes within the tag will not matter.

Comment: the only tag involved is the link tag <link />

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using PHP's [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php).

```
$html = '<link href="/phoenix/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />';
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($html);
echo $xml->attributes()->href;
```